# D3 Leaf Nodes - many elements overlaps

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

i'm using D3JS in the following JSFiddle Example: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/z4qjm51f/1/)

I'm experiencing a strange issue: when i have a lot of leaf nodes on my graph, the leafs overlaps between them, currently, i've tried to use many strategies to go (like the `.separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 5 ) })`) on the nodes but with no luck.

Take note that i can have a D3 Charts with 500/600 leaf nodes and them must be readable.

My goal is to increase the space between the leaf nodes and make them readable and not overlapped, how i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree and cluster layouts will do a separation based on the available space. Therefore, that value you passed is not an absolute value (in pixels, for instance), but just a proportion.

You have to tell D3 how much SVG height (or width) you need. For instance, you can calculate the number of leaves in the `root`...

```
var numberOfLeaves = countLeaves(root);

function countLeaves(obj) {
  var leaves = 0;
  recursiveCounter(obj);
  function recursiveCounter(obj) {
    if (obj.children) {
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
        if (obj.children[i].children) {
          recursiveCounter(obj.children[i]);
        } else {
          leaves++;
        };
      };
    };
  }
  return leaves;
};
```

And change the width accordingly:

```
var nodeHeight = 12;

height = nodeHeight * numberOfLeaves;
```

Here is the code with that change:

```js
var width = 1000,
  height = 1000;
var diameter = 300;
var duration = 2000;

d3.selectAll("input").on("change", change);

function change() {
  if (this.value === "radialtree")
    transitionToRadialTree();
  else if (this.value === "radialcluster")
    transitionToRadialCluster();
  else if (this.value === "tree")
    transitionToTree();
  else
    transitionToCluster();
};

function transitionToRadialTree() {

  var nodes = radialTree.nodes(root), // recalculate layout
    links = radialTree.links(nodes);

  svg.transition().duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," +
      (height / 2) + ")");
  // set appropriate translation (origin in middle of svg)

  link.data(links)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .style("stroke", "#fc8d62")
    .attr("d", radialDiagonal); //get the new radial path

  node.data(nodes)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
    });

  node.select("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .style("stroke", "#984ea3");

};

function transitionToRadialCluster() {

  var nodes = radialCluster.nodes(root), // recalculate layout
    links = radialCluster.links(nodes);

  svg.transition().duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," +
      (height / 2) + ")");
  // set appropriate translation (origin in middle of svg)

  link.data(links)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .style("stroke", "#66c2a5")
    .attr("d", radialDiagonal); //get the new radial path

  node.data(nodes)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
    });

  node.select("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .style("stroke", "#4daf4a");

};

function transitionToTree() {

  var nodes = tree.nodes(root), //recalculate layout
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  svg.transition().duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

  link.data(links)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .style("stroke", "#e78ac3")
    .attr("d", diagonal); // get the new tree path

  node.data(nodes)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  node.select("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .style("stroke", "#377eb8");

};

function transitionToCluster() {

  var nodes = cluster.nodes(root), //recalculate layout
    links = cluster.links(nodes);

  svg.transition().duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

  link.data(links)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .style("stroke", "#8da0cb")
    .attr("d", diagonal); //get the new cluster path

  node.data(nodes)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  node.select("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .style("stroke", "#e41a1c");

};

var root = getData();

var nodeHeight = 12;

var numberOfLeaves = countLeaves(root);

function countLeaves(obj) {
  var leaves = 0;
  recursiveCounter(obj);

  function recursiveCounter(obj) {
    if (obj.children) {
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
        if (obj.children[i].children) {
          recursiveCounter(obj.children[i]);
        } else {
          leaves++;
        };
      };
    };
  }
  return leaves;
};

height = nodeHeight * numberOfLeaves;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .separation(function(a, b) {
    return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 5)
  })
  .size([height, width - 160]);

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
  .separation(function(a, b) {
    return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 5)
  })
  .size([height, width - 160]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });

var radialTree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([360, diameter / 2])
  .separation(function(a, b) {
    return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 5) / a.depth;
  });

var radialCluster = d3.layout.cluster()
  .size([360, diameter / 2])
  .separation(function(a, b) {
    return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 5) / a.depth;
  });

var radialDiagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI];
  });

function responsivefy(svg) {
  // get container + svg aspect ratio
  var container = d3.select(svg.node().parentNode),
    width = parseInt(svg.style("width")),
    height = parseInt(svg.style("height")),
    aspect = width / height;

  // add viewBox and preserveAspectRatio properties,
  // and call resize so that svg resizes on inital page load
  svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMid")
    .call(resize);

  // to register multiple listeners for same event type,
  // you need to add namespace, i.e., 'click.foo'
  // necessary if you call invoke this function for multiple svgs
  // api docs: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on
  d3.select(window).on("resize." + container.attr("id"), resize);

  // get width of container and resize svg to fit it
  function resize() {
    var targetWidth = parseInt(container.style("width"));
    svg.attr("width", targetWidth);
    svg.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
  }
}

var nodes = cluster.nodes(root),
  links = cluster.links(nodes);

var svg = d3.select("#test").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .call(responsivefy)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke", "#8da0cb")
  .attr("d", diagonal);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
  });



node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4.5)
  .style("stroke", "#e41a1c");

node.append("text")
  .attr("dx", function(d) {
    return d.children ? -8 : 8;
  })
  .attr("dy", 3)
  .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
    return d.children ? "end" : "start";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });




function getData() {
  return {
    "name": "This Instance",
    "children": [{
      "name": "TEST",
      "children": [{
        "name": "FM Sala 1 [L1] AC Sala 1 [L2] FM Open Space [L3]",
        "children": [{
          "name": "VLN1"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN2"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN3"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "VL1-2"
        }, {
          "name": "VL2-3"
        }, {
          "name": "VL3-1"
        }, {
          "name": "VLL_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "IL1"
        }, {
          "name": "IL2"
        }, {
          "name": "IL3"
        }, {
          "name": "IL_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "PL1"
        }, {
          "name": "PL2"
        }, {
          "name": "PL3"
        }, {
          "name": "PL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "QL1"
        }, {
          "name": "QL2"
        }, {
          "name": "QL3"
        }, {
          "name": "QL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "SL1"
        }, {
          "name": "SL2"
        }, {
          "name": "SL3"
        }, {
          "name": "SL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_LSUM"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_LSUM"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_LSUM"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "Luci Open Space [L-1-2-3]",
        "children": [{
          "name": "VLN1"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN2"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN3"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "VL1-2"
        }, {
          "name": "VL2-3"
        }, {
          "name": "VL3-1"
        }, {
          "name": "VLL_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "IL1"
        }, {
          "name": "IL2"
        }, {
          "name": "IL3"
        }, {
          "name": "IL_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "PL1"
        }, {
          "name": "PL2"
        }, {
          "name": "PL3"
        }, {
          "name": "QL3"
        }, {
          "name": "QL1"
        }, {
          "name": "QL2"
        }, {
          "name": "QL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "SL1"
        }, {
          "name": "SL2"
        }, {
          "name": "SL3"
        }, {
          "name": "SL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_LSUM"
        }, {
          "name": "PL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_LSUM"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_LSUM"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L1"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "Centrale Termica [L1-2-3]",
        "children": [{
          "name": "VLN1"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN2"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN3"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "VL1-2"
        }, {
          "name": "VL2-3"
        }, {
          "name": "VL3-1"
        }, {
          "name": "VLL_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "IL1"
        }, {
          "name": "IL2"
        }, {
          "name": "IL3"
        }, {
          "name": "IL_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "PL1"
        }, {
          "name": "PL2"
        }, {
          "name": "PL3"
        }, {
          "name": "QL3"
        }, {
          "name": "QL1"
        }, {
          "name": "QL2"
        }, {
          "name": "QL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "SL1"
        }, {
          "name": "SL2"
        }, {
          "name": "SL3"
        }, {
          "name": "SL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_LSUM"
        }, {
          "name": "PL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_LSUM"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_LSUM"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L1"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "UPS Rack Main [L3]",
        "children": [{
          "name": "VLN1"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN2"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN3"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "VL1-2"
        }, {
          "name": "VL2-3"
        }, {
          "name": "VL3-1"
        }, {
          "name": "VLL_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "IL1"
        }, {
          "name": "IL2"
        }, {
          "name": "IL3"
        }, {
          "name": "IL_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "PL1"
        }, {
          "name": "PL2"
        }, {
          "name": "PL3"
        }, {
          "name": "QL3"
        }, {
          "name": "QL1"
        }, {
          "name": "QL2"
        }, {
          "name": "QL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "SL1"
        }, {
          "name": "SL2"
        }, {
          "name": "SL3"
        }, {
          "name": "SL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_LSUM"
        }, {
          "name": "PL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_LSUM"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_LSUM"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L1"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "Generale [L-1-2-3]",
        "children": [{
          "name": "VLN1"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN2"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN3"
        }, {
          "name": "VLN_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "VL1-2"
        }, {
          "name": "VL2-3"
        }, {
          "name": "VL3-1"
        }, {
          "name": "VLL_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "IL1"
        }, {
          "name": "IL2"
        }, {
          "name": "IL3"
        }, {
          "name": "IL_AVG"
        }, {
          "name": "PL1"
        }, {
          "name": "PL2"
        }, {
          "name": "PL3"
        }, {
          "name": "QL3"
        }, {
          "name": "QL1"
        }, {
          "name": "QL2"
        }, {
          "name": "QL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "SL1"
        }, {
          "name": "SL2"
        }, {
          "name": "SL3"
        }, {
          "name": "SL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "Cos_LSUM"
        }, {
          "name": "PL_SUM"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "kWh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L1"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVAh_LSUM"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_LSUM"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L3"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L2"
        }, {
          "name": "KVARh_L1"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "open space",
        "children": [{
          "name": "dbm"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "Luxmetro reception",
        "children": [{
          "name": "lux"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "Gathered - Gate 1",
        "children": [{
          "name": "people_count"
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "test",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Open Space",
        "children": [{
          "name": "carbon_oxide"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  };
}
```

```css
   label {
     font: 12px sans-serif;
   }

   .node circle {
     fill: #fff;
     stroke: steelblue;
     stroke-width: 1.5px;
   }

   .node {
     font: 10px sans-serif;
   }

   .link {
     fill: none;
     stroke: tan;
     stroke-width: 1.5px;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="radialtree">Radial Tree</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="radialcluster">Radial Cluster</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="tree">Tree</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="cluster" checked>Cluster</label>
</form>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

You have to do a similar math for the `diameter`.